# Migrating from Craft CMS to WordPress

Tags: migration

I have recently discovered our company website is run on Craft CMS. However, I do not like the system and am much more proficient on WordPress. Is there a way to move our site to WordPress without a huge bill or running/migration issues.

Comment: Hi Ken - there are ways to export data from Craft CMS and I am sure there are ways to import data in Wordpress.  But think very very very carefully about this - if you do some research you will see CraftCMS is a very highly respected system, and there is a significant flow of folks FROM Wordpress TO Craft, and probably, for good reason, not many going back the other way.  Perhaps it's time to embrace change and learn a more modern, vastly better engineered system?

Comment: did you figure this out? Sorry to revive an old thread but I'm looking to do exactly this...

Answer (score 5):

It’s likely possible but would be tricky, since Craft has much more flexible content modeling features than WP. It would be a “lossy” conversion process, similar to converting a WAV file to a low bitrate MP3.

The best way to get content out of Craft is probably to use the [Element API](https://plugins.craftcms.com/element-api) plugin. I couldn’t tell you how to get that content into WP though – you may have better luck asking about that on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Before you go down this road, it’s probably worth spending just a bit of time learning Craft CMS. You never know, you might just end up liking it! Here are a few recent articles that compare the two:

- Roller Agency: [Why we are moving to Craft CMS](https://medium.com/roller-agency/why-we-are-moving-to-craft-cms-4cbaee017c0d)
- Trajectory: [Craft vs Wordpress: The Definitive Guide](https://www.trajectorywebdesign.com/blog/craft-vs-wordpress/)
- OneSignal: [Lessons Learned Building Our Website With Craft CMS](https://onesignal.com/blog/craft-cms/)
- Honcho Agency: [Why We're Craft CMS Developers](https://honcho.agency/blog/why-were-craft-cms-developers)

If interested, I highly recommend you check out CraftQuest’s [Up and Running with Craft 3](https://craftquest.io/courses/craft-cms-3-tutorials) course, which is free.